# Strange "caching issue" with an MVC app using JQuery load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an action which uses the JQuery Load event to call out to a controller method and retrieve data, this works fine, i click a button, and new content comes back. However, after the thrird click it stops getting data. I have added a breakpoint at the top of the method and noticed it being hit 3 times, and then not being hit. Here is my jquery code:

```
function callAction() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Method", "Controller", new { type = "test" })';
    $("#divToLoadData").load(url);
}
```

As I said, this loads the data, each time i click a link to call that function, but after the third retrieval, it fails to call the method and retrieve data. I've tried using $.ajax as well, and had a similar outcome.

Anyone come across similar??

Comment: Did you try ajax with `cache:false` option ?

Comment: I did indeed, no luck with that either :(

Comment: Did you inspect if the request is being sent, and what is being returned from server when you click that after 3rd time using firebugs `net` tab or chrome's `network` tab in developer tool.

Comment: Yep, after the certain number of requests that it stops at, nothing seems to get sent. Though if I wait about 2 minutes, my breakpoint gets hit again... something very unusual is going on...

Answer (score 0):

Since `jQuery.load()` performs GET browser may cache the result of the request and serve it instead of hitting the server. You can force the browser to always send the request to the server by setting content expiration headers. Decorate your action with this attribute:

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
            return;

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working either, I set a breakpoint in the attribute, to make sure it was being hit aswell and the context was being set, this was a hit a few times, and then also stopped. Though I've now noticed some strange behaviour, after clicking the link a few times after it doesn't come back with any data, the actual application itself freezes...

Comment: Do you mean your browser freezes?

Comment: No, the browser doesn't freeze, just the application itself

Comment: What do you mean by freezes? Is CPU going 100%? Is web server not handling any more requests? - looks like you have a problem somewhere else...

Comment: It appears as though the webserver itself is not handling any requests after a certain number of requests. After a couple of minutes, it responds again with the correct data, but this seems to be after a consistent number of requests, which currently is 3. It's very unusual...

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using? Are you running Win XP? You might want to turn off keep-alives...